# Angular 5 - Show Module in Component

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular5

I have my app in which I would like to have several types of `progress-loader-animations` (`spinner`/`bar`/etc.)

Therefore I have created a module with a component. How would I now show up the module's spinner in my `main-component`?

Comment: Show what you tried and created codding.

Comment: @DiabolicWords .. so what.. all cool names were already in use

Answer (score 0):

1. Import your class `ProgressLoaderAnimations` at the top of your
   `app.module.ts`. and add it to the `declarations:` array
2. Use the selector string referenced in Angular @Component directory
       within your custom progress-loader component's `html` template.

```js
import { ProgressLoaderAnimations } from './progress-loader-animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProgressLoaderAnimations // Note this.
  ],
  providers: [
    BackendService,
    HeroService,
    Logger
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'progress-loader-animations',
  templateUrl: './hero-list.component.html',
  providers: []
})
export class ProgressLoaderAnimations implements OnInit {

  /* . . . */
}
```

It would be nice to have more information (i.e. your code) or a plnkr, stackblitz, etc.

The steps outlined here should be enough information to resolve your issues with the components and further reading into the Angular tutorial, if necessary.

There are other optimisations in loading components that could be investigated, for example (lazy-loading).

Components reference: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components

Also a step-by-step walkthrough should be **extremely** beneficial for you, as it was for me. https://angular.io/tutorial

[Googled Stackblitz example of HeroDetailComponent used in HeroListComponent](https://stackblitz.com/angular/plmkaagkxqy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)